# Rails 3.2 silence logging deprecation warning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

In Rails 3.2 I get deprecation warning, when using logger.silence {}. In release note:
"ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger#silence is deprecated. If you want to squelch logs for a certain block, change the log level for that block."

How I can easily change log level for the block?

Answer (score 4):

It appears that `logger.silence` is being replaced by simply `silence`:

```
logger.silence do
    #your silenced code here
end
```

becomes:

```
silence do
    #your silenced code here
end
```

At least it doesn't generate the depreciation warning anymore, and it does silence the logged output.

Comment: silence should have one argument, shouldn't it?
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb#L97

Comment: This doesn't work at all in Rails 3.2.x and kuboon is correct in that plain 'silence' needs an argument.

Answer (score 3):

The first answer is good, but not complete.  We were having issues trying to figure this one out too.  `silence &block` has been deprecated in Rails 3, so you should use the updated syntax calling the logger directly:

```
Rails.logger.silence do
  # your code here...
end
```

For even more sweet, sweet customizability, you can pass a log level to #silence().

Answer (score 2):

```
def silent_method
  old_level = Rails.logger.level
  Rails.logger.level = 7

  result = your_code_here

  Rails.logger.level = old_level

  result
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Or [`quietly{}`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.21/classes/Kernel.html#method-i-quietly), since `silence` requires a stream.